# SimpleDateFormat appears to fail with "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS0"

Tags: java, parsing, date, formatting

Why doesn't the following work? It appears that the literal zero at the end is the cause...

```
final DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS0");
format.setLenient(false);

String d = format.format(new Date());
System.out.println(format.parse(d));
```

Comment: Why do you need the zero at the end of the format?

Comment: the milliseconds in my dataset happen to have a bunch of zeros right after the milliseconds... no idea why

Comment: @cellige - can you please update question with some values from your dataset.

Comment: The code above formats out a value for you, and yet it can't parse it back in.

Comment: Milliseconds are just 3 digits, how is your data saved in your database, using a char/varchar or a date/datetime/timestamp value? In case of char/varchar, you could trim the other 0 values that add no value to your data.

Comment: @cellige - yeh..sorry for above comment..at first i misunderstood the question

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza yes I could, and I am of course but does it not strike anyone as a bug in the class? Or am i not using it correctly?

Comment: @Saurabh my fault, I am not very clear at times :)

Comment: Ah I see, I thought that since SSS was the 3 digit format that it would only look at those, but it parses a number and fails. Thanks !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not know why would you need to add the zero (0) at the end of your pattern, but you should wrap the not pattern letters inside '' to make them work:

```
final DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'0'");
```

More info:

- [Java `SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), Examples section at the beginning of the documentation.

---

The problem with your code is in this line

```
System.out.println(format.parse(d));
```

Trying to parse more than 3-digit milliseconds to java.util.Date will result in an exception. The pattern to parse the String should be

```
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS" //without the zero at the end, now your whole code will work...
```

If you're working with nanoseconds or your data have them, you could ignore these values, also nanoseconds are not supported in Java Date/Time API (in the documentation they don't even mention it).

If you really, really need to have the nanoseconds for diverse purposes, then you should stick to use a String instead of a Date object.

Comment: Not to mention the documentation says that the quoting is for the letter formatters. Doesn't say you need it, and from my little testing doesn't appear to make a difference for digits.

Comment: How do your date value looks like? Why would you want to parse a date with an additional zero?

Comment: @RichardSitze if you're a scientist and need to use the nanoseconds for whatever operation you could need, you should handle these values by yourself, the Java API can't help you on this. Still, there is the `System.nanoTime()` method that handles the current time with nanoseconds in a long variable. You could come up with a nice way to convert up to the millisecond part in long, then multiplicate it by 1000 and add the nanoseconds (lot of hard work...)

Comment: @Luiggi your answer is correct in so far as describing the behavior of parse wrt milliseconds.  However I believe the correct "answer" is simply that SimpleDateFormat.parse doesn't implement the described spec.  I see this as a (minor) defect.  You've described the limitations, and have suggested reasonable work-arounds - and that's great.  To add to the misery, your suggestion of quoting should also work... and it doesn't.

Comment: @RichardSitze I've edited the answer. The problem is not in the format, is in the parse, as I've explained in a different section.